# Adding even tiny send delay to a UDP speed test makes it 100x slower

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, io, udp

I'm currently trying to compare the speeds of TCP and UDP for the purposes of a science project. I am sending 10000 packets of 100 bytes each over a local network (currently only on one computer) and measuring the time (clientside) it takes for 10000 packets to be received. I got my program to work, however, TCP appeared much faster than UDP, which should not be the case for this experiment (although, it IS an experiment, so technically those results could be valid...).

---

I investigated the problem by counting the amount of UDP packets that were sent, and then comparing them to the amount of packets that were received. This turned out to be shocking, as I found 3000+ packets were sent, but not received on the client side. To fix this, I tried adding a short delay (1ms) to each UDP packet send (serverside only) but then found that that delay (quite frustratingly) slowed the total transmission time down by nearly 100x. I then reduced the delay to around 12 nanoseconds and found the same effect (again to my chagrin). I expected for this delay to give the client some time to catch up... not to mysteriously slow my code down by 100x!!!

Can anyone help me? My code is at https://github.com/Archonic944/ProtocolSpeedTest.

Comment: Clocks and timers in Java are limited by the clock resolution of timers that are available to the JVM.  This is OS specific, but on some platforms, application code won't get better than millisecond resolution ... even if they do sleeps with times specified in nanoseconds.

Comment: So ... when you think you are adding a 12 nanosecond delay, that is not what is actually happening.  A `sleep` has overheads of hundreds of nanoseconds for just the syscall.  Then you have the issue that the OS thread scheduler cannot guarantee to wake a thread up immediately when the sleep timer expires.  (You need an RT operating system.)  Finally, you have the issue of the OS's sleep timer resolution.  If the OS only checks sleep wakeups on (say) a 1 millisecond "tick", that's all you get.

Comment: You don't mention what version of Java you are using, or what version of what operating system you are using.

Comment: *"TCP appeared much faster than UDP, which should not be the case for this experiment"* - if your expectation is that UDP should be faster than TCP then your expectation is wrong. TCP optimizes for bandwidth use. Your "packets 100 bytes each" will each be a single packet with UDP  but about 14..15 of these 100 bytes will be combined in a single packet with TCP, meaning much less overhead.

Comment: This makes sense, but it still doesn't explain the dropping of 3000 packets that I experience when sending through UDP. Also, I am running macOS Ventura and my version of Java is 1.8.0.